# Can't change MFC Button Caption

Tags: c++, mfc

```
int firstButton = IDC_BUTTON1;  

for(int i = firstButton; i < firstButton + 16; ++i)
{
    CWnd *pB = GetDlgItem(i);

    for(int j = 0; j < 16; ++j)
    {

        pB->SetWindowTextW((LPCTSTR)(szTest[j]));
    }
}
```

I want to change button caption dynamically.

when in use SetWindowTextW with static text like "static txt" it works well,

but with char array (in this case szTest), the captions are'nt changed

Am i coded a wrong type casting?

Comment: You can't just cast a `char` array to a `wchar_t` array, you have to convert it. Plenty of questions here on how to do so, just do a search.

Comment: I do not understand your inner loop. It looks like you assign 16 different strings in a row to the button caption.

Comment: @Hamidi i have a 16 size of char array, and want to insert in button caption one by one charc

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. I suppose you have 16 buttons on your dialog. Please tell us what szTest looks like and what each button should contain once the outer for loop is finished.

Comment: @MichaelWalz yes, i have a 16 buttons on my dialog, and szTest is char szTest[16]; and each button should have a one character from szTest

Comment: So if you have char szTest[] = "0123456789ABCDEF" you want "A" in the first button,, "B" in the second butto, "C" in the 3rd button etc. ? If yes look on my forecoming answer. If no, please post some more code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The inner for loop in your code doesn't make sens to me. 
You probably want this:

```
char szTest[] = "0123456789ABCDEF" ;

int firstButton = IDC_BUTTON1;  

for (int i = firstButton; i < firstButton + 16; ++i)
{
    CWnd *pB = GetDlgItem(i);
    CString str(szTest[i]) ;
    pB->SetWindowText(str);
}
```

With that piece of code, the first button will contain "0", the second will contain "1" etc.